# QQuickWidget touch screen pen input

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtwidgets

I am trying to get pen or finger input from touch screen (Panasonic Toughbook). In the qml side i can not get click or tap input. I have tried the TapHandler with all pointer types and devices but it does not work. I can click with pen if i use QWidget (for example QPushButton) but qml does not work. I also check the events. I can take mouse events for QQuickWidget but does not work for qml.

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Item {
    id: root

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#bed3d4"
        focus: true

        TapHandler {
            enabled: true
            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
            onTapped: {
                console.log("Clicked")
            }
        }

        TapHandler {
            enabled: true
            acceptedPointerTypes: PointerDevice.AllPointerTypes
            acceptedDevices: PointerDevice.AllDevices
            onTapped: {
                console.log("Tapped")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this code click works but tap doesn't.

Comment: As I know `TapHandler`should be attached to some item to fill it bounds. Does it work on desktop? Please update your question and provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out to enable touch input in QQuickWidget you have to enable WA_AcceptTouchEvents flag with setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents).